# Specify Maximum File Size while uploading a file in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sts

I am creating temporary credentials via AWS Security Token Service (AWS STS).
And Using these credentials to upload a file to S3 from S3 JAVA SDK.
I need some way to restrict the size of file upload.
I was trying to add policy(of s3:content-length-range) while creating a user, but that doesn't seem to work.
Is there any other way to specify the maximum file size which user can upload??

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please post your code, so the other people may take a look at what you tried already and then advice solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is no way to limit the object size before uploading, and reacting to that would be quite hard. A workaround would be to create an [S3 event notification](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html) that triggers your code, through a Lambda funcation or SNS topic. That could validate or delete the object and notify the user for example.

Comment: But, I believe in Browser Based POST Policy we can specify content-length-range, which can restrict uploading big files. The same is not able in SDK.

Comment: `content-length-range` suggested in the question is an HTML form `POST` policy condition (not an IAM policy condition).  Uploads using pre-signed forms do support this kind of limitation, but that is the only such mechanism.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html

Answer (score 6):

An alternative method would be to generate a pre-signed URL instead of temporary credentials. It will be good for one file with a name you specify. You can also force a content length range when you generate the URL. Your user will get URL and will have to use a specific method (POST/PUT/etc.) for the request. They set the content while you set everything else.

I'm not sure how to do that with [Java](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html) (it doesn't seem to have support for conditions), but it's simple with [Python and boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3.html#generating-presigned-urls):

```
import boto3

# Get the service client
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

# Make sure everything posted is publicly readable
fields = {"acl": "private"}

# Ensure that the ACL isn't changed and restrict the user to a length
# between 10 and 100.
conditions = [
    {"acl": "private"},
    ["content-length-range", 10, 100]
]

# Generate the POST attributes
post = s3.generate_presigned_post(
    Bucket='bucket-name',
    Key='key-name',
    Fields=fields,
    Conditions=conditions
)
```

When testing this make sure every single header item matches or you'd get vague access denied errors. It can take a while to match it completely.